# Neural Networks: Why does the perceptron rule only work for linearly separable data?

Tags: machine-learning, computer-science, neural-network

I previously [asked](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13976565/neural-networks-what-does-linearly-separable-mean) for an explanation of linearly separable data. Still reading Mitchell's Machine Learning book, I have some trouble understanding why exactly the perceptron rule only works for linearly separable data?

Mitchell defines a perceptron as follows:
[image: The perceptron]

That is, it is y is 1 or -1 if the sum of the weighted inputs exceeds some threshold.

Now, the problem is to determine a weight vector that causes the perceptron to produce the correct output (1 or -1) for each of the given training examples. One way of achieving this is through the perceptron rule:

> One way to learn an acceptable weight vector is to begin with random
>   weights, then iteratively apply the perceptron to each training
>   example, modify- ing the perceptron weights whenever it misclassifies
>   an example. This process is repeated, iterating through the training
>   examples as many times as needed until the perceptron classifies all
>   training examples correctly. Weights are modified at each step
>   according to the perceptron training rule, which revises the weight wi
>   associated with input xi according to the rule:
>   [image: The perceptron rule]

So, my question is: Why does this only work with linearly separable data? Thanks.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Because the dot product of `w` and `x` is a linear combination of `x`s, and you, in fact, split your data into 2 classes using a hyperplane `a_1 x_1 + … + a_n x_n > 0`

Consider a 2D example: `X = (x, y)` and `W = (a, b)` then `X * W = a*x + b*y`. `sgn` returns 1 if its argument is greater than 0, that is, for class #1 you have `a*x + b*y > 0`, which is equivalent to `y > -a/b x` (assuming b != 0). And this equation is **linear** and divides a 2D plane into 2 parts.

Comment: Sorry, my head exploded. I don't quite follow (no strong background in maths). Could you elaborate? :)

Specifically, I don't quite understand: "2 classes using hyperplane a_1 x_1 + … + a_n x_n > 0" and "And this equation in linear and divides 2D plane into 2 parts"...

Comment: `a_1 x_1 + … + a_n x_n` > 0 formes a ((n-1)-dimensional, but it doesn't matter) hyperplane in a n-dimensional space. It is analogous to a line (a 1-dimensional object) in a 2D space (plane). So for an arbitrary point is either `w * x > 0` or `w * x <= 0`. That's why # of classes is 2.

Comment: `y > -a/b x` is just `y = -a/b x` with equality replaced with inequality. It's easy to see that for inequality version for arbitrary `x` we should take all `y`s lying higher than point `y = -a/b x`