# Artificial Neural Network for formula classification/calculation

Tags: machine-learning, neural-network

I am trying to create an ANN for calculating/classifying a/any formula.

I initially tried to replicate Fibonacci  Sequence.  I using the inputs:

- [1,2] output [3]
- [2,3] output [5]
- [3,5] output [8]
- etc...

The issue I am trying to overcome is how to normalize the data that could be potentially infinite or scale exponentially?  I then tried to create an ANN to calculate the slope-intercept formula y = mx+b (2x+2) with inputs

- [1] output [4]
- [2] output [6]
- etc...

Again I do not know how to normalize the data.  If I normalize only the training data how would the network be able to calculate or classify with inputs outside of what was used for normalization?

So would it be possible to create an ANN to calculate/classify the formula ((a+2b+c^2+3d-5e) modulo 2), where the formula is unknown, but the inputs (some) a,b,c,d,and e are given as well as the output? Essentially classifying whether the calculations output is odd or even and the inputs are between -+infinity...

Comment: Are you saying that you're trying to use ANNs in place of formulas or are you saying that you're trying to calculate some property of the formula's output? If it's the former, what is your ultimate goal?

Comment: I would say, the first option.  I am trying to use the ANN in place of the formula.  The formula is unknown, but the output will be 0 or 1.  I guess I also forgot to mention the inputs are may or may or may not be unrelated.  However to my understanding of ANNs this should not be an issue.  I, as a human, will not know the formula, but would like the ANN to 'understand/learn' the formula.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Okay, I think I understand what you're trying to do now. Basically, you are going to have a set of inputs representing the coefficients of a function. You want the ANN to tell you whether the function, with those coefficients, will produce an even or an odd output. Let me know if that's wrong. There are a few potential issues here:

First, while it is possible to use a neural network to do addition, it is not generally very efficient. You also need to set your ANN up in a very specific way, either by using a different node type than is usually used, or by setting up complicated recurrent topologies. This would explain your lack of success with the Fibonacci sequence and the line equation.

But there's a more fundamental problem. You might have heard that ANNs are general function approximators. However, in this case, the function that the ANN is learning won't be your formula. When you have an ANN that is learning to output either 0 or 1 in response to a set of inputs, it's actually trying to learn a function for a line (or set of lines, or hyperplane, depending on the topology) that separates all of the inputs for which the output should be 0 from all of the inputs for which the output should be 1. (see the answers to [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13976565/neural-networks-what-does-linearly-separable-mean) for a more thorough explanation, with pictures). So the question, then, is whether or not there is a hyperplane that separates coefficients that will result in an even output from coefficients that will result in an odd output.

I'm inclined to say that the answer to that question is no. If you consider the `a` coefficient in your example, for instance, you will see that every time you increment or decrement it by 1, the correct output switches. The same is true for the c, d, and e terms. This means that there aren't big clumps of relatively similar inputs that all return the same output.

Why do you need to know whether the output of an unknown function is even or odd? There might be other, more appropriate techniques.